# Problem drawing curved paths with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw small process flow graph, but I'm having two problems with the layout:

- The edges from the bottom nodes B, C should curve out and around back to A, not go directly on the inside. I thought that `bend left` and `bend right` would do this, but they don't seem to have any effect.
- The text on some edges needs more isolation from other elements. Can I specify an offset from the drawn edge to place the text?

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,auto,main node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw,align=center}]

  \node[main node] (1) {$A$};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {$D$};
  \node[main node] (4) [below of=2] {$B$};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=1] {$E$};
  \node[main node] (5) [below of=3] {$C$};

  \path
  (1) edge node [left] {$d$} (2)
      edge node [right] {$e$} (3)
  (2) edge node [below] {$b$} (4)
  (3) edge node [below] {$c$} (5)
  (4) edge node [bend left] {$a$} (1)
  (5) edge node [bend right] {$a$} (1);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: For your information, the `below of` keys are deprecated: [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You've added `bend left` as an option for the `node`, but it should be as an option to the `edge`, that's why they don't have any effect. You can also specify an angle, e.g. `bend left=45`, to change the bending.
2. The two labels that are on top of the lines are there because the lines are vertical and you specified `below` as the relative node position. If you use `left`/`right` instead, or remove the placement specifier altogether, they're placed next to the lines. (Note that this automatic placement next to the path does not apply for normal lines, e.g. `(a) -- (b)`, only for `edge`s [I think, not very familiar with `edge`, so I don't how it works in detail].)

   To push them further away, you can say e.g. `left=<length>`.

In the below code I used `swap` to change which side the node is placed on. The angles for `bend left`/`bend right` were found by trial and error.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,auto,main node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw,align=center}]

\node[main node] (1) {$A$};
\node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {$D$};
\node[main node] (4) [below of=2] {$B$};
\node[main node] (3) [below right of=1] {$E$};
\node[main node] (5) [below of=3] {$C$};

\path
(1) edge node [swap] {$d$} (2)
    edge node  {$e$} (3)
(2) edge node [swap] {$b$} (4)
(3) edge node  {$c$} (5)
(4) edge [bend left=60] node  {$a$} (1)
(5) edge [bend right=60] node[swap]  {$a$} (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One more question; suppose that there was more text in the D and E boxes. Is there any easy way to move the a arrows farther out to prevent them from colliding?

Comment: Depending on how much text there is, you could possibly get away with just changing the bend angle. "Worst case", you have to use a different way of drawing that path, for example `\draw (4) ..controls +(-3,2) and +(-3,0) .. (1) node[midway,left]{$a$};`. There may well be better ways, I'm, not really an expert.

Comment: @ddcc You could also use a auxiliary coordinate, say `([xshift=-1cm] 2.west)` that you use on the way.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the 'in' and 'out' angle of the edges, then it looks like this (i took the liberty of renaming your nodes...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=2.5cm,auto,main node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw,align=center}]

\node[main node] (A) {$A$};
\node[main node] (D) [below left of=A] {$D$};
\node[main node] (B) [below of=D] {$B$};
\node[main node] (E) [below right of=A] {$E$};
\node[main node] (C) [below of=E] {$C$};

\path (A) edge node [left] {$d$} (D);
\path (A) edge node [right] {$e$} (E);
\path (D) edge node [right] {$b$} (B);
\path (E) edge node [left] {$c$} (C);
\path (B) edge [out=135,in=180] node [left] {$a$} (A);
\path (C) edge [out=45,in=0] node [right] {$a$} (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, it seems that @Torbjørn T. just beat me to the answer by some minutes :)